# How to pause your script in Selenium untill your AutoIt script is completed?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, autoit

I want Selenium to wait until and unless an AutoIt script is completed.

Right now whats happening is when I run the `TestNG.xml` file it runs all the @Test Priority wise and within 5 sec the TestNg output console shows all the @Test are passed.
While my AutoIt scripts are still running in parallel in the background.

The code is as follows:

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");       
}

@Test (priority=2)
public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
}
```

The AutoIt code is as follows:

```
createnew()

Func createnew()
    Sleep(2000)
    Run("Mspaint.exe")
    WinWaitActive("Untitled - Paint")
    Send("!f")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("n")
    Sleep(2000)
    WinClose("Untitled - Paint")
EndFunc   ;==>createnew
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer borrows from Paul [answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-selenium-with-java/20761#20761)

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");
p.waitFor();       
}

@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods={"CreateNew"})
public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
}
```

By adding the wait onto the process it will wait for it to end.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler solution is try a `waitFor()` on your process, this waits until the process exits.

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");
    process.waitFor();
    Integer result = process.exitValue();
    Assert.AssertEquals(0, result) 
}
```

Now you can add an `exit` code to the AutoIt script to communicate that it passed or failed. Read about exit codes here: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Exit.htm

Otherwise try something like this:

- In your Java/Selenium code create a temparory lockfile
- Start Autoit.exe
- In your Java/Selenium code write a loop to check if lockfile still exists
- Last step in the AutoIt code removes the lockfile
- If the lockfile doesnt exist break out of loop and continue with the next code

Some considerations:

- Add a timeout to your loop in case the AutoIt script does not clean up the lockfile.
- Add a timestamp and testname to the lockfiles name (e.g. testname_timestamp.lck) so that you can run tests in parallel
- Clean all lockfiles when starting a testsuite

Comment: Can you just give an Example of How to create a "lockfile" for this?

Comment: The lockfile is just a concept. Its a file on disk that when exists it blocks another process from starting. Just create the file with the Java file tools: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: Here is a link about the locking concept "Lock your script (against parallel execution)": http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex

Comment: Add waitFor(), this is easier i think :)

Comment: That process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)  is helping, but it will PASS the script even when the AutoIt script is failed.

Comment: I think you do not need to add wait for one minute, what if the autoit script runs for 2 minutes? I have added an exit code example to my answer this way you can communicate from AutoIt if the test passed or not.