# How to implement a lock in Selenium with Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, autoit

I want the Script to `Openfile.exe` only if the previous one i.e `CreateNew.exe` has finished executing.

Right Now whats happening is, when I run `TestNG.xml` file it runs all the `@Test` priority wise and within 5 sec `TestNg` output console shows all the `@Test` are passed.

While my AutoIT scripts are still running in parallel in background.

The code is as follows:

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");       
}

@Test (priority=2)
public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
}
```

And the code of AutoIt file is as Follows:

```
createnew()

Func createnew()
    Sleep(2000)
    Run("Mspaint.exe")
    WinWaitActive("Untitled - Paint")
    Send("!f")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("n")
    Sleep(2000)
    WinClose("Untitled - Paint")
EndFunc   ;==>createnew
```

A possible solution for this can be:-

- In your Java/Selenium code create a **temparory lockfile**
- Start Autoit.exe
- In your Java/Selenium code write a loop to check if lockfile still exists
- Last step in the AutoIt code removes the lockfile
- If the lockfile doesn't exist break out of loop and continue with the next code

**Now does anyone know how to create and use this lockfile in code?**

Comment: That process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) is helping, but it will PASS the script even when the AutoIt script is failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer borrows from NarendraC's answers.

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");
    p.waitFor();       
}

@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods={"CreateNew"})
public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
}
```

The issue, from what I could tell, was that the first method exited prior to completion. By adding the wait onto the process it will wait for it to end. This will, I believe, give you the desired result.

Comment: That process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) is helping, but it will PASS the script even when the AutoIt script is failed.

Comment: Well, depending on how the AutoIT script fails, you can assign the result of the p.waitFor() to an int which will give the result. I would recommend a new question if you need further details.

Comment: nice elaboration paul ! voted up :)

Answer (score 1):

Even why cant you try "**dependsOnMethods**", This will be useful in that sense.

*Check out below example for use:*

```
@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods={"CreateNew"})
```

Comment: because the first will finished before the .exe is finished and the second will be started instantly.

Comment: Oh, Its my bad. Can you try - Keep openFile.exe on Priority=1 and createNew on Priority=2. and then implement dependsOnMethods, It will definitely give you colorful result. Give a try

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal Solvable by waiting for the process to end.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better (though more complicated) way of doing it, instead of thread sleep, is to use a messaging queue and publish/subscribe model.

Comment: how would the java code communicate with the AutoIt code to implement a publish/subscribe model? Doesnt that only work within one single piece of code.